# Does resetting a Roland D-5 or D-20 erase all the sounds on it?

Tags: synthesizer

I just picked up a Roland D-5 and a D-20 synthesizer but I want to reset them to their factory preset sounds. I understand from the [answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/how-to-reset-a-roland-d-20/1249#1249) to [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/how-to-reset-a-roland-d-20) that I can reset the device, but I'm not sure if the procedure described restores the synth to factory settings, or simply erases everything. Which is it? I am interested only in a factory reset - I don't want to end up erasing everything and then have no sounds at all.

Comment: I edited this question pretty heavily based on information in Bill's answer (now deleted) to that other question. This question is not about how to perform a reset, it's about whether that reset deletes everything or reinitializes the data to a factory state. I believe it stands on its own now.

Comment: Thanks @Warrior Bob, I have deleted my previous comments to clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://www.dlse.nl/synthrepair/reset.html), the D-5 cannot be reset, but the D-20 can.

From what I can tell, resetting the D-20 will put it back to factory defaults without losing all the sounds.  (see the comments on [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/roland-d20-how-to-use-midi/1281#1281))